# .net Core odata json property return corrupted data

Tags: c#, rest, entity-framework, asp.net-core, odata

I'm developing .net core ODATA web api application.
I have EF entity Operation with Json serialized property PaymentProfile.
I have problem with getting Operation.PaymentProfile.PaymentMethods property via ODATA request

Configuration of Operation fluent API:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Operation>().Property(e => e.PaymentProfile).HasConversion(
        v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v, JsonSerializerSettings),
        v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaymentProfile>(v, JsonSerializerSettings));
```

PaymentProfile is entity with other properties like:

```
public ICollection<PaymentMethod> PaymentMethods { get; set; } = new List<PaymentMethod>();
public CascadeStrategy CascadeStrategy { get; set; }
```

When i get request with expan of CascadeStrategy, it works fine:

> odata/Operations?$expand=PaymentProfile($expand=CascadeStrategy)&$top=1&skip=0

Server return correct odata objects

**But if i expand PaymentMethods property, it return corruped data with 200 http status**.
Request:

> odata/Operations?$expand=PaymentProfile($expand=PaymentMethods)&$top=1&skip=0

Response:

> {"@odata.context":"http://localhost:5020/odata/$metadata#Operations(PaymentProfile(PaymentMethods()))","value":[

If i request PaymentProfile with expand PaymentMethods, it works fine too:

> odata/PaymentProfiles?$expand=PaymentMethods&$top=1&skip=0

Operation and PaymentProfile are from different EF context.

*How can i fix it and get Operation.PaymentProfile.PaymentMethods property? Any ideas?*

UPD: "currepted data" means response is not finished and is a not valid JSON. Lookse like its only first 112 symbols of true response

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the `Accept` header when requesting `CascadeStrategy` while `PaymentMethods` didn't?

```
Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=none
```

In general, the request results have `@odata.context`, which is what you call corrupted data. You can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/concepts/get-data).

If you don't want it to appear, you can add `Accept` header like above, you can also add `$format=application/json;odata.metadata=none` to the query string, which will remove odata metadata from the results:

```
odata/Operations?$format=application/json;odata.metadata=none&$expand=PaymentProfile($expand=PaymentMethods)&$top=1&skip=0
```

Comment: thnks for response, i've update question

Comment: Hi @Timur Lemeshko, could you please provide more details? For example, a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Do you might know the answer to this one as well?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75245865/copybatchrequestproperties-and-deleterequestcontainer-replacement-in-aspnetcore